# Saying InshaAllah for 'bad' things (Sunni View)

Tags: sunni

Is it fine to say InshaAllah in the following situations (at the end of each sentence)?
"I will not die a disbeliever", "I think I will fail my test", "I will never commit murder".
These refer to the future, but somehow it feels like saying InshaAllah means that I want it to happen

Comment: the secode one about the test I would definitely NOT say... the other two are fine IMO.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but I think this will be beneficial- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iAX_oHVjLac

Answer (score 9):

Arabic: **إن شاء الله** ; Transliteration: ***`"In-Shaa-Allah"`***

It means ***`"If Allah Wills"`***. it has nothing to do with, "I want it to happen".

However, people use it when they wish for something good to be happened by Allah.

Basically it comes in no harm to say 
***"If Allah wills, I will not die a disbeliever"
or 

"If Allah wills, I think I will fail my test" or 

"If Allah wills, I will never commit murder"***

Comment: please provide reliable source

Comment: `"In-Shaa-Allah"` (إن شاء الله)is Arabic. You need reliable sources for a language? If so, try google translate:
http://translate.google.com/#ar/en/%D8%A5%D9%86%20%D8%B4%D8%A7%D8%A1%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87

Comment: I meant fatwa...